# How to set an alarmManager that shows a notification on specific time

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-notifications

I am developing an app in which I am finding current date and time and calculating date and time after 7 days. In which I got success but I want to set Notification on that date which I had calculated. How can I do that

code to find out current date and time and end date and time:-

```
private void endTime(){
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 500);

    endTime = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) + "/" +
            String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)) + " " + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":" +
            String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) + ":" + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    Log.e(TAG,"End Time::"+endTime);
}

private void currentTime() {

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    currentTime = String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)) + "/" +
            String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.YEAR)) + " " + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)) + ":" +
            String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.MINUTE)) + ":" + String.valueOf(c.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    Log.e(TAG,"Current Time::"+currentTime);


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create one service class extends With `IntentService` to run it in background

```
 Intent intentToQB = new Intent(YourActivity.this, BackgroundService.class);

  PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),1212, intentToQB, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
  alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,calendar.getTimeInMillis(),5*60*1000, pendingIntent);
```